# Can you view the layer mask in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, mask

In GIMP, after adding a layer mask, and editing, is there a way (or even a plugin) to let you view the layer mask right on the canvas?  I know that you can see a miniature copy of the layer mask in the Layer Dialog on the side (right next to the miniature copy of the layer), but I want to know if you can just view it?

(I suppose alternatively, I could do a greyscale layer and copy that layer onto the mask, but I was more interested in if there was an easy one-click method to make this happen.)

Comment: Have you seen the [manual](http://docs.gimp.org/ca/gimp-layer-mask-show.html)?

Answer (score 1):

In the image menu, just toggle the `Layer->Mask->Show Layer Mask` when the layer of interest is active. Or, just `Alt+Click` on the miniature of the mask, on the layer's dialog (again to turn its view off).

Some Window managers capture "Alt + Click" - (that is, the control is used to move the Window around, and GIMP itself never knows about the click). If that is your case, `Ctrl + Alt + Click` on the mask thumbnail instead.